# Changing the structure of csv data

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, csv

I'm trying to change data looking like this:
[original csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkrPv.png)

into this format:

```
name = "The V Girl";
author = "Mya Robarts";
pages = 341;
imageURL = "https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1441452466l/25437891._SY475_.jpg";
description = "A long description...";
```

Could I ask for pointers?

Comment: I can't really see the relation between your between and after data

Comment: Thank you, edited to make it more obvious.

Comment: CSV is textual file format whereas your example looks like Excel worksheet.

Comment: I opened CSV in Excel.

Comment: Does you need to copy the data from source sheet looks like shown one onto another sheet with the format described?

Comment: That would do the trick. I need the format to look *exactly* as I've shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume source sheet is "Sheet1"

Enter the formulas onto the sheet "Sheet2":

```
A1=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MOD(ROW()-1,5)+5,,,"Sheet1")) & " = "
B1="""" & INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2+INT((ROW()-1)/5),MOD(ROW()-1,5)+5,,,"Sheet1")) & """"
```

Drag these cells down until all source data occures. Copy - Paste Special - Values. Export.

Maybe it is safe to edit the source - for example, remove "pages" word from column 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to modify data when you are importing data from CSV to Excel, then try this:

1. Open the CSV from card DATA -> Get & Transform -> New Query -> From CSV - open the CSV file
2. Click on Transform (Edit / modify) - sorry, I have Czech language set in Excel
3. In next Screen you can rename columns and add new columns with Power Query M formula for editing values in queries (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/power-query-m-reference) - you can use text functions to find a comma and print data before comma to edit values in column "pages"
4. After editing your data "Close and Load"

Best regards, Lukas